# Помогите пожалуйста доделать регурярку (не работает квантификатор)

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Нужно распарсить список прокси, одна строка из которого выглядит так:

```
23 192.169.214.83:63828 SOCKS5  HIA 2.374   US Скоттсдейл (Аризона) ip-192-169-214-83.ip.secureserver.net (GoDaddy.com, LLC)    100% (9)    07:10:19 13:00
```

Нужно выделить следующие группы:
id: 23
ip: 192.169.214.83
port: 63828
delay: 2.374
uptime: 100
tests: 9

На regex101 составил такое выражение:

```
(\d{1,5}) (\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):(\d{1,5}).+(\d{1,2}\.\d{1,3}).+(\d{3}).+(\d+)\)
```

Проблема в том, что процент uptime может быть и не 3 цифры (100), а 2 (ниже не интересно). Пытаюсь писать в предпоследней группе не `(\d{3})`, а `(\d{2,3})` - и оно тогда не захватывает первую цифру (в данном случае выходит "00"). Как правильно в этом случае нужно написать, чтобы корректно захватывало и 100 и меньшие двухзначные значения?

Comment: `.*\D(\d{2,3})` - https://regex101.com/r/yr9w6L/1

Comment: @splash58. Спасибо, работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно заменить `.+(\d{3})` на `.+?(\d{2,3})%`.

Но вообще лучше нормально делить на колонки и не подменять `\s+` на `.+`.

Comment: Так 100 не захватывает (

Comment: @Iceman, должен захватывать. А что захватывает?

Comment: 100% пропускает - `   US Скоттсдейл (Аризона) ip-192-169-214-83.ip.secureserver.net (GoDaddy.com, LLC)    100% (`. Берёт "192" - первое число из IP. Процент надо было в группу добавить - `.+?(\d{2,3}%)`

Comment: Так ты не в том месте поменял - надо было там, где проценты. А, понял. Поправил.